# Java petitparser optional end of expression

Tags: java, petitparser

I need a parser that took only important marked parts from a text file.
This is sample input:

```
else before 1
else before 2
--Start Query 1
important 1
--End 1
else between 1 and 2 - 1
else between 1 and 2 - 2
--Start Query 2
important 2
--End 2 
else after1-1
else after1-2
```

I wrote this parser:

```java
public class ExpressionDefinition extends GrammarDefinition {
        {
            def("start", ref("expr").star().end());
            def("nl",  of("\r\n").or(of("\n").or(of("\r"))));
            def("expr", 
                    ref("else").starLazy(ref("expr_start").flatten())
                    .seq(ref("expr_start"))
                    .seq(ref("expr_body"))
                    .seq(ref("expr_end"))
                    .seq(ref("else").starLazy(ref("expr_start")).optional()).map(in -> {
                        if (in instanceof List) {
                            for (Object o: (List)in) {
                                if (o instanceof Body) {
                                    return o;
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }));
            def("expr_start", of("--Start Query").seq(any().starLazy(ref("nl")), ref("nl")));
            def("expr_body", any().starLazy(ref("expr_end")).flatten().map((String in) -> new Body(in)));
            def("expr_end", of("--End").seq(any().starLazy(ref("nl")).optional(), ref("nl").optional()));
            def("else", any().starLazy(ref("nl")).seq(ref("nl")));
        }
```

With this small utility Pojo for getting important data:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Body {
    private final String val;
    @Override public String toString() { return val; }
}
```

Run like:

```java
ExpressionDefinition def = new ExpressionDefinition();
Parser parser = def.build();
Result result = parser.parse(input);
```

And it throw me an exception:
`org.petitparser.context.ParseError: end of input expected`
But no visible reason why, as the last line is `else` kind of content and we expecting to have it with star condition, and its a part of `expr`: `ref("else").starLazy(ref("expr_start")).optional()`

How can I change the parser, so it will expect et the end of each `expr` to be any amount of `else` with and without possible new-line character at the end of the input? Making `else` just greed makes it consume the second `expr_body`. Making it `any().optional()` cause infinite loop hang.
Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to use the `a.delimitedBy(b)` operator, which gives you a parser that consumes `a` one or more times separated and possibly ended by the argument `b`. If you need more control, have a look at how it is [implemented](https://github.com/petitparser/java-petitparser/blob/45ffbd197cfda5f0dfb043ecfa0da2619355bbec/petitparser-core/src/main/java/org/petitparser/parser/Parser.java#L437).

Comment: thanks! the question is outdated thou, because based on this:https://github.com/petitparser/java-petitparser/issues/34 question the delimiter logic has changed. Anyway, this works without; `.end()`.  `end of input expected`? not anymore!